# Date Picker Extension for Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension, datepicker

I need a chrome extension that will give me start a date picker for specific fields in a specific web page. Whenever someone clicks in one of the date fields a date picker should be show to the user, either above the fields or anywhere in the webpage and insert the selected date into the fields. I have been trying to do it, but no success so far. Here are the details:

The Webpage that this extension should be active: http://www.smartfleetonline.co.in/internet/trans_hist.jsp

[image: The image from the link]

The Code behind the fields is:

```
<input type="text" name="fromday" size="1" maxlength="2" value="">
<input type="text" name="frommonth" size="1" maxlength="2" value="">
<input type="text" name="fromyear" size="2" maxlength="4" value="">

<input type="text" name="today" size="1" maxlength="2" value="">
<input type="text" name="tomonth" size="1" maxlength="2" value="">
<input type="text" name="toyear" size="2" maxlength="4" value="">
```

Even sample code would be very helpful. How to include jQuery UI elements in my plugin?
Or is there any other plugin that will help me regarding this?

Comment: do you require 3 input fields for a date?

Comment: I agree with you. We don't. But I did not develop it. I'm just trying to make life easier for a lot of people who use that site by developing a chrome extension for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why only for Chrome, try this datepicker out: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Of course it will work for all modern browsers because it is a jQuery, and you don`t care about the browser the user is using ;)

Comment: Yes, jQuery Datepicker plugin is the solution. But I need it to work with a Chrome Extension/plugin and I need a way to do this.